Android Jetpack Compose: How to expand a search icon into a searchbar overlaying on adjacent UI buttons?
I need a search icon and some UI buttons placed next to the search icon. When user clicks on the search icon I would like it to expand into a searchbar hiding the adjacent UI buttons.
The other alternative I am looking for is to have a searchbar (instead of search icon) and UI buttons overlaid on the search bar. Again when user clicks on search bar, the buttons get hidden.
I want something like this:
_____________________________
| SearchIcon      Button      |
 _____________________________
| ListItem1                   |
| ListItem2                   |
...



And when the SearchIcon is clicked, I would like the Button to be hidden and Searchbar to appear like this:
 _____________________________
|         Searchbar           |
 _____________________________
| ListItem1                   |
| ListItem2                   |
...


An alternative:
_____________________________
| Searchbar       Button      |
 _____________________________
| ListItem1                   |
| ListItem2                   |
...



And when the Searchbar is clicked, I would like the Button to be hidden and Searchbar to extend to the screen width like this:
 _____________________________
|         Searchbar           |
 _____________________________
| ListItem1                   |
| ListItem2                   |
...


I have SearchBar implementation as below, which populates the list items. If I make the SearchBar conditionally visible, then the list too will be conditionally visible. How to resolve this?
    SearchBar(
        inputField = {
            SearchBarDefaults.InputField(
                query = searchText,
                onQueryChange = { viewModel.onSearchTextChange(it) },
                onSearch = {
                    expanded = true
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                },
                expanded = true,
                onExpandedChange = { expanded = true },
                placeholder = {
                    Text( text = "Search")
                },
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Search,
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            expanded = true
                            viewModel.onSearchTextClose()
                            focusManager.clearFocus()
                        })
                },
            )
        },
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            if (searchText.isNotBlank()) {
                viewModel.onSearchTextClose()
            } else {
                val activity = context as Activity
                activity.finish()
            }
        },
    )
    {
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState,
        )
        {
            items(items) { item ->
                Row() { /* List item */
                }
            }
        }
    }

The search bar is already in place, which needs to be changed into a search icon and a button needs to be added adjacent to it.
Here is the GUI snapshot:
snapshot

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Search(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var isSearchClicked by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isSearchClicked.not()) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(60.dp)
                    .background(Color.Gray),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Search,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    Modifier.clickable {
                        isSearchClicked = true
                    })
                Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }
        }
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isSearchClicked) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                    .padding(top = 10.dp),
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Search")}
            )
        }
    }
}

Also, you can set the custom animation as per your requirements.

Thanks Hanif for the response. As updated in the Question, I already have SearchBar implementation, making it invisible makes the list invisible too.

@Saral Can you please attach a GUI that will help me understand better?

Hanif, I have added the GUI snapshot
